# Select two rows from MySQL database as one dependent on attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, freeradius

I have FreeRADIUS that has a MySQL database backend. Users are stored in radcheck table:

[image: radcheck table image]

I want to select from it all users (there will be more users in the near future) with username, speed profile and password. So I will get as e result lukasfazik, testovacieheslo, OPTIK100.
I have tried this:

```
SELECT  username, password, profile
FROM (SELECT t1.username, t1.value AS password, t2.value AS profile
      FROM radcheck AS t1, radcheck AS t2
      WHERE t1.value != t2.value
     ) AS arrgh;
```

And I got this from it:

[image: result from my query image]

GROUP BY doesn't work, I get an error:

> [42000][1055] Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'arrgh.password' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: (1) Your query has no `GROUP BY`, so your question doesn't make sense.  (2) Your query has no `JOIN`, and yet it is attempting a join.  That is also a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to pivot your table. The most simple way to do that in this case would be to join the table to itself. For more complex cases you can look at this [guide](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78):

```
select a.*, b.password 
from (username, value profile from FreeRADIUS where attribute = 'user-profile') a
join (username, value password from FreeRADIUS where attribute = 'cleartext-password') b 
on a.username = b.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the attributes you want using sub-queries and join them:

```sql
> SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT username, value as profile FROM radcheck WHERE attribute = "User-Profile") as t1
NATURAL JOIN
    (SELECT username, value as pass FROM radcheck WHERE attribute = "Cleartext-Password") as t2
;

+------------+----------+-----------------+
| username   | profile  | pass            |
+------------+----------+-----------------+
| lukasfazik | OPTIK100 | testovacieheslo |
+------------+----------+-----------------+
```

The sub-query will contain the username and the value of the selected attribute from your main table.

```sql
> SELECT username, value as profile FROM radcheck WHERE attribute = "User-Profile"

+------------+-----------+
| _username_ | _profile_ |
+------------+-----------+
| lukasfazik | OPTIK100  |
+------------+-----------+
| testuser   | OPTIK200  |
+------------+-----------+
| fooUser    | OPTIK500  |
+------------+-----------+
| ...        | ...       |
+------------+-----------+
```

More attributes can be added similarly, by nesting the natural joins.